# Lowest temperature that sensors can measure

Tags: battery, cpu

So I've doing some work and phone wasn't in my pocket but in room where temperature was low (let's say about 3°C) I was curios what phones battery and cpu temperature sensors say and you see what they were saying. So what is lowest temperature which they can measure?
[image]

Comment: It may depend on the sensor your device have and I will not suggest exposing device to extremes to measure its sensor limit

Comment: Many cell phones have operating limits for temperature, for example the Nexus 5x's manual states the operating temperature of the device is between -4°F and 122°F which would probably cover most devices, yours is well within that limit. The sensor's operating conditions could be different, and it would vary based on manufacturer and firmware, but clearly those readings are incorrect. 1080°C is the melting point of copper, so I highly doubt that is correct.

Comment: @acejavelin so you say my phone isn't limited on which temperature he can operate, meaning that it may work on possibly dangerous temperatures?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "dangerous"...  -4°F/-20°C to 122°F/50°C are hardly dangerous in my book. I can tell you from living in a varied climate area that the phone will operate outside these ranges for limited times as well (I have used my phone in -30°F/-35°C but not for very long). Extreme cold for extended periods will shutdown a device, and excessively high temps will cause this as well, the phone will throttle itself to attempt to cool off, then will shutdown to protect itself.

Comment: @acejavelin So in your opinion what is lowest and highest temperature (°C)  in which phone should be used, without worrying of damgeing device

Comment: For extended periods of use, I would say -4°F/-20°C to 122°F/50°C is a good rule of thumb. Your device manufacturer should have stated operating conditions that are supported.

Comment: @acejavelin ok thanks form an asnwer from theese coments, I found out what I want from them.